# Converting C Program To CUDA (Max Reduction)

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, max, reduction

I am new to CUDA and trying to get a grasp for the basic so I apologize if something I ask or say sounds overly simple. I wrote some serial code in C for generating an array with random numbers and then finding the max within this array.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
    #include <time.h> /* time */

    #define num 100000

    int *arr,max = -1;

    int getRand() {
        double r1=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; // Generates value between 0 & 1
        return (r1 * num) + 1;
    }
    void generateRandom(int M) {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
            arr[i] = getRand();
        }
    }
    void getMax(int M) {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
            if(arr[i] > max)
                max = arr[i];
            }
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
        if (argc == 2) {
            int M;
            /* initialize random seed: */
            srand (time(NULL));
            M = atoi(argv[1]);
            //int arr[M];
            arr = (int*)calloc(M,sizeof(int));;

            //printf("M = %d MAX = %d\n", M, RAND_MAX);

            generateRandom(M);

            getMax(M);

            printf("Max value: %d",max);

        }

        else
            printf("Invalid arguments.");

        return 0;
    }
```

I am now trying to convert this code into a simple CUDA program. I tried just making the generateRandom function run as a kernel but I am getting problems with the memory management.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> /* time */
#include <cuda.h>

#define num 100000

int *arr,max = -1;

int getRand() {
    double r1=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; // Generates value between 0 & 1
    return (r1 * num) + 1;
}
void generateRandom(int M) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
        arr[i] = getRand();
    }
}
__global__ void getMax(int M) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
        if(arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if (argc == 2) {
        int M;
        /* initialize random seed: */
        srand (time(NULL));
        M = atoi(argv[1]);
        //int arr[M];
        arr = (int*)calloc(M,sizeof(int));

        //printf("M = %d MAX = %d\n", M, RAND_MAX);

        generateRandom(M);

        getMax<<<1,1>>>(M);

        printf("Max value: %d",max);

    }

    else
        printf("Invalid arguments.");

    return 0;
}
```

That code resulted in the following errors.

> cudabasic.cu(23): warning: a host variable "arr" cannot be directly read in >a device function
>
> cudabasic.cu(23): warning: a host variable "max" cannot be directly read in >a device function
>
> cudabasic.cu(24): warning: a host variable "arr" cannot be directly read in >a device function
>
> cudabasic.cu(24): warning: a host variable "max" cannot be directly written >in a device function

I googled the error and found out that the problem was that I was passing global variables to a kernel and thus the device wasnt able to read it. Following an online suggestion I tried to solve this by using pointers rather than passing actual variables but I am still getting errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> /* time */
#include <cuda.h>

#define num 100000

int *arr,max = -1;

int getRand() {
    double r1=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; // Generates value between 0 & 1
    return (r1 * num) + 1;
}
void generateRandom(int M) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
        arr[i] = getRand();
    }
}
__global__ void getMax(int M, int *dArr, int *dMax) {
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int a = dArr[i];
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
        if(a > dMax)
            dMax = a;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if (argc == 2) {
        int M;
        /* initialize random seed: */
        srand (time(NULL));
        M = atoi(argv[1]);
        //int arr[M];
        arr = (int*)calloc(M,sizeof(int));
        devArr = (int*)cudaMalloc(M,sizeof(int));

        //printf("M = %d MAX = %d\n", M, RAND_MAX);

        generateRandom(M);

        getMax<<<1,1>>>(M, arr, max);

        printf("Max value: %d",max);

    }

    else
        printf("Invalid arguments.");

    return 0;
}
```

> cudabasic.cu(24): error: operand types are incompatible ("int" and "int *")
>
> cudabasic.cu(25): error: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an >entity of type "int *"

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to best go about doing this this?

I am new to CUDA and trying to get a grasp for the basic so I apologize if something I ask or say sounds overly simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best advice I can offer is to study some introductory CUDA programming material such as [this](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/GTC_Express_Sarah_Tariq_June2011.pdf). Your code  displays a lack of understanding not only of CUDA, but of basic C concepts (like variables must be defined before they are used in expressions.)  As a CUDA programmer, don't "flush" your knowledge of how to write proper C or C++ code.    If you google things like "gtc cuda intro" or "gtc cuda optimization" you'll find good CUDA learning material.

The approach you're following, which is to take a single-threaded C/C++ code, and convert it to run using a single CUDA thread might give you some warm and fuzzy feelings about "learning CUDA" but you're not really tackling any of the important concepts - and it shows in the code you're struggling with right now.

To get the last code you presented functional a few more steps are needed:

1. In CUDA, device pointers can't normally be dereferenced in host code, and normally, host pointers can't be used in device code.  This means that you generally shouldn't pass host pointers to a device kernel:

   ```
   getMax<<<1,1>>>(M, arr, max);
                      ^^^  ^^^
   ```

   you were on the way to fixing the `arr` issue with your `devArray` (although your `cudaMalloc` is not set up properly), we just need to fix it and complete that with an additional `cudaMemcpy` operation to copy the host data to the device.  If you're not sure how to use a function like `cudaMalloc`, don't just guess your way through it and use casts to force types to other types - that's often a sign that you're not handling it correctly:

   ```
   devArr = (int*)cudaMalloc(M,sizeof(int));
   ```

   instead refer to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356).  We also need to handle `max` correctly - it is currently a host pointer and we will need a device copy of that data.
2. Your kernel is also a bit jumbled.  Since you are launching only a single CUDA thread, your `threadIdx.x` variable will only (ever) be zero:

   ```
   int i = threadIdx.x;
   int a = dArr[i];
   ```

   but the for-loop in the kernel will work, we just need to move some lines around.
3. Although you haven't gotten to the point of a compilable, runnable code, it's always a good idea to do [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  I've added my own version to the code below.

The following code has the above issues addressed, and seems to return a sane result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> /* time */
#include <cuda.h>

#define num 100000

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


int *arr,my_max = -1;

int getRand() {
    double r1=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; // Generates value between 0 & 1
    return (r1 * num) + 1;
}
void generateRandom(int M) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
        arr[i] = getRand();
    }
}
__global__ void getMax(int M, int *dArr, int *dMax) {
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++) {
        int a = dArr[i];
        if(a > *dMax)
            *dMax = a;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if (argc == 2) {
        int M;
        int *devArr, *devMax;
        /* initialize random seed: */
        srand (time(NULL));
        M = atoi(argv[1]);
        //int arr[M];
        arr = (int*)calloc(M,sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc(&devArr,M*sizeof(int));
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc 1 fail");
        cudaMalloc(&devMax,sizeof(int));
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc 2 fail");
        cudaMemset(devMax, 0, sizeof(int));
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemset fail");
        //printf("M = %d MAX = %d\n", M, RAND_MAX);

        generateRandom(M);
        cudaMemcpy(devArr, arr, M*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 1 fail");
        getMax<<<1,1>>>(M, devArr, devMax);
        cudaMemcpy(&my_max, devMax, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2/kernel fail");
        printf("Max value: %d \n", my_max);

    }

    else
        printf("Invalid arguments.");

    return 0;
}
```

After you've understood the above changes, you'll want to go back to my original advice and get some organized CUDA learning.  At that point, if you want to re-visit max-finding, then the "good" way to do it is with a proper parallel reduction technique.  A "reduction" is an algorithm that takes a (large) data set and returns a single number or a small set of numbers as a result.  Finding the max in an array is an example of a "reduction".  You can learn more about proper CUDA parallel reductions by studying [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) and working through the CUDA parallel reduction [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanations they have been very helpful. The reason I was using threadIdx.x was because I want to now make this code use multiple threads ( i guess I was getting a little ahead of myself). Would you be able to show me how this might be done as well?

Also I have tried looking at the sample code you linked to but I can figure out where to view the code. The page lists reduction - CUDA Parallel Reduction and the versions supported but I dont understand how to view the actual code.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include my first attempt, unfortunately it wasnt very successful. Im gonna see if I can fix it but if you could offer some advice that would be very helpful.

Comment: Making wholesale changes to your question makes my answer confusing for future readers.  I'd suggest asking a new question.  SO isn't intended to be a chat session or a running dialog.  Your "new" code still has glaring defects.  For example, you're launching 64 blocks of 1 thread each.  In that case, `threadIdx.x` will *still* always be zero.  Trying to put together CUDA knowledge this way is very tedious.  Why not use some of the material I linked?  If you did, you would understand why `threadIdx.x` will *still* always be zero in your new code.

Comment: Regarding the sample, click on the link corresponding to your operating system.  You'll then be taken to a portion of that page that indicates where the samples are usually installed and where you can view them and how to build them on your machine.